# Cannot stop LOCATION_SERVICE

Tags: android, gps

I have a simple application that uses the Android system service LOCATION_SERVICE. On app close I need the service to stop. I have searched hard and long for how to do this but I must not be looking for the right thing. Does anybody know how to stop this service?

Here is what I'm doing.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    lm = (LocationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        0, 
        0, 
        locationListener);

    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The LocationManager class does not seem to have any methods to stop the service. That's where I thought you would be able to close or stop it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure `onDestroy()` is being called? If you're just exiting the app with the home/back button then it most likely is not. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: To add to what eldarerathis said, you probably want to start and stop collection in onStart and onStop, or onPause and onResume so that it stops when you go into the background.

Comment: That's just one of many ways that I've tried. I also tried onBackPressed() which does execute. But that's not really my problem. I just want to close the location service.

Comment: @Mayra Your talking about the listener right? I don't think the service will stop just because the listener stops.

Comment: Since the location service is a system managed service, I"m not sure why you would be responsible for doing anything other than cleaning up your listeners..

Comment: You would think so. But the GPS keeps running after I leave the app. When I hit the back button to get out the onBackPressed() should be called and I have the lm.removeUpdates(locationListener) in that method. This should stop the listener right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call finish() in the onBackPressed() function to close your application. Then the onDestroy should be called to.

There is no need to stop the location service (guess you're talking about GPS). GPS won't be used if there is no application listening to it,  hence not consume any CPU power or battery.

Comment: Yeah I've tried all that. Pretty much it looks like the application is still running even after I back out from the app. Do you know how I can make sure that the application actually closes when I back out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `@Override`.
I've tested this and got the same problem. And with `@Override` my application crashes.

I also think, that you're using the wrong method. onDestroy is the last one you should execute. Just have a look at the activity documentation there is a diagram showing the involved methods for an application.

[link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

I'm trying to do the same as you and I've used onResume and onPause to activate and deactivate the LocationUpdates.